# Profit maximizing with demand function

Tags: calculus, self-learning, economics

Cost function is $c(q)=q$

Demand function is $q(p) = 100/p$ for $p\le 20$. And $q(p)=0$ for $p>20$.

In order to calculate profit maximizing output and price

$$max [p(q)*q-q]$$

And marginal revenue = marginal cost for FOC.

But I cannot get proper result. Why? Please help me to calculate this or give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Is $c(q)$ the total cost function or the unit cost function?

Comment: The question is not specified. I guess total cost function @callculus

Comment: In this case you have a constant revenue of 100  but increasing costs. Thus the maximum profit is where the cost are minimum.This is at q=0. Thus the maximum revenu=profit is $profit(0)=100$

Comment: You said for $p>20$. So it is not possible for other one $p<20$. I’m confused a bit. Please expand your answer? @callculus

Comment: You´re right. Good catch. Then take $q=5\Rightarrow p=20$. The maximum profit is $95$

Comment: Okay what you said is true. But there is a mistake for $p>20$. When $p>20$, demand $q=0$ so revenue = q(p)*p= 0*p=0. That for $p>20$, revenue is zero. Since price is greater than 20, profit becomes negative. @callculus

Comment: I don´t really understand what you mean. If p=20 the price is not greater that 20. It is true that if p>20 the profit is negative. This sounds logic to me since the revenue is 0. Above a price of 20 nobody buys a unit of the good.

Comment: @callculus I see. Thank you so much. Can you look at that question which is continue of above question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758044/profit-maximization-question

Comment: You´re welcome. I have already seen your question. I think I will look more closely tomorrow. Here in Germany it is almost midnight.

Comment: No worries whenever you have time. Then have a good night to you! And see you please  @callculus